# SuiteScript Sublist Pagination Not Updating As Expected

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm very new to SuiteScript and I'm struggling with something hope somebody knows the answer. Any help is appreciated. Here are the details:

1. Adding a tab
2. Adding a sublist
3. Adding 30 elements into the sublist (NetSuite paginates 25 records at a time)
4. When I select **26 to 30 of 30** option from the dropdown, the sublist is not being updated.

```
  const subTab = form.addTab({
    id: "custpage_tab_mehmet",
    label: "MTab",
  });

  const subList = form.addSublist({
    id: "custpage_sublist_mehmet",
    label: "MSublist",
    tab: "custpage_tab_mehmet",
    type: ui.SublistType.STATICLIST
  });

  subList.addField({
    id: "custpage_column_one",
    label: "Col 1",
    type: ui.FieldType.TEXT
  })

  for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
    subList.setSublistValue({
      id: "custpage_column_one",
      line: index,
      value: `col1 row${index}`
    });
  }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried changing the `type` to `ui.SublistType.LIST` but then the whole built-in pagination setup is gone. I'm only seeing a complete list of 30 items.

Comment: IMO sublists barely work and worked better in SS1. If your use case can support it you are better off avoiding STATICLIST. If I need morefunctionality than what the other list types provide I just embed an inlinehtml and manage the lists as Javascript.